# Неправильно склонение

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть код:

```
<?php
$users = dle_cache('procore_users', $config['skin']);

if (!$users) {
    $row = $db->super_query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM '.PREFIX.'_users');
    $users = $row['count'];
    create_cache('procore_users', $users, $config['skin']);
}

function declOfNum($num, $titles) {
    $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    return $titles[($num%100>4 && $num%100<20)? 2 : $cases[min($num%10, 5)]];
}

$endWord = declOfNum($allcount , array('ь', 'я', 'ей'));
echo "<span>{$users}<span class='day_user'></span></span> <font>пользовател{$endWord}</font>";

?>
```

Почему-то **при значении 51** он выдает слово **пользователей**.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что проблема вызвана опечаткой и ответ не несёт пользы другим программистам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Всё работает верно](http://ideone.com/2B3jru)

Вы уверены, что значение переменной `$allcount` именно 51? Или что вместо `$allcount` не должно быть `$users`?

Comment: Точно, не заметил. Большое вас спасибо!